# Interactive with TextView in each row of ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an list View with two Item in each row is two TextView.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/my_textview_border"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:maxWidth="240dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I want to show the hidden TextView just on the row I click with `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method but how can I set an detail id for each TextView. I mean the TextView just VISIBLE in the row I touch, not all of that TextView in other row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extend your class `Activity` by `implements OnItemClickListener`
2. use `yourList.setOnItemClickListener(this);` in `onCreate()`
3. Override `onItemClick` using this way:

s

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

4. do not forget to override your `getView()` arrayAdapter method:

a

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list) {
View element;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    element = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.yourlayout, null);
                } else {
                    element = convertView;
                }
///setup your listview element
return element;
}
```

**EDIT**

to change all data for textview I will work in such way:
yourarrayadater.setupmydata();
yourarrayadater.notifyDataSetChanged()

after that arrayadapter will redraw using `getView`.
So, use again

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list) {
    View element;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        element = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.yourlayout, null);
                    } else {
                        element = convertView;
                    }

TextView tv = (TextView) element.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    ///SETUP YOUR tv for each row
    return element;
    }
```

Comment: Solved :D Thank you.

Comment: Now I want to change that TextView in all row. So how can I get that TextView? I used parent.findViewById() but not work.

Comment: No, not the data. I meant the View :D Actually I want the last tvInfo TextView GONE when I click the other